# Rename everything before brackets for files

Tags: regex, linux, rename

So I have a bunch of files who go like this : Yu-Gi-Oh! Zexal -  Magic (S01E40).mp4 and I try to rename all of my files like this : S01E40 , I tried this command  :

`rename 'y/(\((?>[^)(]+|\g<1>)*\))//' *.mp4`

Nothing changed .

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: `rename 's/.*\(.*\).*/$1/' *.mp4 `
`Use of uninitialized value $1 in substitution (s///) at (eval 4) line 1.`
`Can't rename Yu-Gi-Oh! Zexal - Mystérieuse disparition (S01E41).mp4 : No such  file or directory `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
rename 's/.*\((.*)\).*(\.mp4)$/$1$2/' *.mp4
```

It will only keep what is in last parentheses and the extension.

`y///` is the same as `tr///`, i.e. transliteration, which exchanges characters one by one. `s///` is for substitution.